# File locked after encryption

Tags: vb.net

I have a small app that is designed to go through a folder and encrypt all the files and delete the non-encrypted version. The encryption works correctly but when I go to delete the file it is locked. Once the app is closed the file is no longer locked. My code is

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim path As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    Dim parent As DirectoryInfo = Directory.GetParent(path)
    Dim completions As String = parent.FullName & "\Attachments_Completions"
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(completions)
    Dim fi As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As FileInfo
    For Each dra In fi
        If dra.Name <> "Completions.txt" And dra.Name <> "Attachments.txt" Then
            Dim tmpFileName As String = String.Format("{0}\qqzr_{1}", dra.DirectoryName, dra.Name)
            Dim encryptedName As String = String.Format("{0}\{1}", dra.DirectoryName, dra.Name)
            FileSystem.Rename(String.Format("{0}\{1}", dra.DirectoryName, dra.Name), String.Format("{0}\qqzr_{1}", dra.DirectoryName, dra.Name))
            cryptFile(tmpFileName, encryptedName, False)
            File.Delete(tmpFileName)
        End if
    Next
End Sub

Sub cryptFile(ByVal sInputFilename As String, ByVal sOutputFilename As String, ByVal switch As Boolean) 
    ' * Used to Encrypt or Decrypt a file
    ' ***********************************
    Dim sKey As String = "a2#R|+~"
    Try
        Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
        DES.Key() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

        'Read the input file into array
        Dim fsInput As New FileStream(sInputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim bytearrayinput(fsInput.Length - 1) As Byte
        fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)

        'Define the crypto transformer
        Dim cryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform

        If switch Then
            cryptoTransform = DES.CreateEncryptor()
        Else
            cryptoTransform = DES.CreateDecryptor
        End If

        'Create the encrypting streams
        Dim fsEncrypted As New FileStream(sOutputFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Dim cryptostream As New CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        'Write the output file
        cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
        cryptostream.Close()
        cryptostream.Dispose()
        'Release the input file
        fsInput.Close()
        fsInput.Dispose()
        'Release the output file
        fsEncrypted.Close()
        fsEncrypted.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Can anyone help?
Cheers
James

Comment: You're positive it's not catching any exceptions and just exiting out of the crypt routine before it closes and disposes `fsInput`?

Comment: I double checked  the execution and `fsInput` is definitely disposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.

I have managed to resolve the problem by adding `File.SetAttributes(tmpFileName, FileAttributes.Normal)` before the File.Delete command

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

```
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

...and see what happens...

Comment: Thanks for that but there were no errors in the execution.